# Add a remove button for Cart component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the "Cart" component using react-redux and want to implement a "Remove" button in the component! I tried create the function within  however when I click it "products" are not be removed and returning an error: "product is undefined". I have alerady a remove button in another component where using redux the product been removed so it works,  however I want to have the button as well in the "Cart" component its self to be able to see the products that been removed!
My cart component code is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Card, CardBody, CardHeader, CardTitle, Row, Col } from "reactstrap"
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js"
import { addCart } from "../redux/actions";
import { removeCart } from "../redux/actions";


class Cart extends Component {
  render () {
    const cart = this.props.cart
    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h4">Products List</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>#</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Code Item</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Price Total</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {cart.length > 0 && cart.map((cart, index) => (             
                      <tr key={cart.id}>
                    <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                    <td>{cart.title}</td>
                    <td>{cart.code}</td>
                    <td>{cart.quantity}</td>
                    <td>{cart.price}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      <span>
                       <button onClick ={() => (removeCart(product))}>Remove</button>
                      </span>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
      cart: state.cart
       }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { 
      return {
        addCart: (product) => {dispatch(addCart(product))},
        removeCart: (product) => {dispatch(removeCart(product))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You want to remove the cart or the product inside the cart?

Comment: @ Pershraw Hasan I want to remove the product inside the cart!

Answer (score 0):

Product is not defined because you don't have anything inside your component called product you haven't declare it, If you want to remove the entire cart then send the id of the cart instead of the (product) and if you want to remove a specific product inside the cart then you might send the id of a specific product not the entire product object.

Comment: @ Pershraw Hasan How could achieve both cases? Remove only a product from cart or empty the entire cart? Any ideas?

Comment: For the first one (remove only a product from a cart) you should send the id of the product to the delete function that you created then filtering out every product by comparing the id of the products inside that cart and the id of the product that you send, then returning back a new array of products that doesn't consist the product that you send the id of, and for the second one (empty an entire card) you can do that by creating a function to removing every product inside the cart (return an empty array).